# Email button to call Web Service

Tags: web-services, email, html-email

I am creating an email that is sent to customers from my website. This email is triggered when the customer clicks an "Ask for Price" button. The email is then sent to our sellers with the information about the customer and the product they are requesting.

On this email, we want to allow the seller the option to directly respond to the customer, but I would like to have this trigger a flag in my database to show that the seller replied to the customer.

Comment: What does "ws" mean in your subject line? And I don't understand *who* is clicking which button and *who* is getting which information. => Either clarify or remove this (if it's unnecessary for the question).

Comment: I'm sorry for bad description... 
-WS I mean WebService call
-My case is: 
Customer will come to my website, there he is interesting about some item... cellphone, laptop, etc. which are selling in 5 stores. Customer click to button "ask for price"... our website send email to all 5 reselers with customer request...when reseller want, can answer direct to customer... but I want to have some flaq in my DB that this reseller will reply to customer...

Is description better? :)

Comment: Are you sending this via an ESP (Email Service Provider) or through your own email service ( custom PHP, Java, etc)?

Comment: For this time I havent nothing, but we starts code this. So I try to find some  solutions, how will this possible...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this.

- You could have them respond to the customer by clicking on a mailto link that fills in the **to** address and the **bcc** address that emails some key information picked up by a script on the server (e.g. customernumber_some_keys@yourscriptwatchedserver.com)
- The email message going to the sellers could have a link to respond to the customer that goes to a landing page on your server with a form for their response, which in turn sends the message and adds information to the database